# How to apply the same function on paired elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, function

I have this code where I would like each textbox input will change its corresponding image. The function itself is typical for all partners in the list (txt & img). I've searched and read somewhat similar post but it's just beyond me at this point. How to make the function work without copying it multiple times?
Please help and thanks in advance :)

**HTML**

```
<div id="sideleft">
<div class="pict" id="img01"></div>
<div class="pict" id="img02"></div>
<div class="pict" id="img03"></div>
<div class="pict" id="img04"></div>
<div class="pict" id="img05"></div>
<div class="pict" id="img06"></div>
<div class="pict" id="img07"></div>
<div class="pict" id="img08"></div>
<div class="pict" id="img09"></div>
</div>

<div id="sideright">
<input class="box" id="txt01" type="text" value="" onblur="change01()"/>
<input class="box" id="txt02" type="text" value="" onblur="change02()"/>
<input class="box" id="txt03" type="text" value="" onblur="change()"/>
<input class="box" id="txt04" type="text" value="" onblur="change()"/>
<input class="box" id="txt05" type="text" value="" onblur="change()"/>
<input class="box" id="txt06" type="text" value="" onblur="change()"/>
<input class="box" id="txt07" type="text" value="" onblur="change()"/>
<input class="box" id="txt08" type="text" value="" onblur="change()"/>
<input class="box" id="txt09" type="text" value="" onblur="change()"/>
</div>
```

```
function change01() {
var image = "";
var answers = document.getElementById("txt01").value;
switch(answers) {
case "a": image='<img src="https://dummyimage.com/55X55/00a2ff/fff"></img>'; break;
case "b": image='<img src="https://dummyimage.com/55X55/1eff00/fff"></img>'; break;
case "c": image='<img src="https://dummyimage.com/55X55/ff0000/fff"></img>'; break;
case "":  image='<img src="https://dummyimage.com/55X55/000000/fff"></img>'; break;
default:  image='<img src="https://dummyimage.com/55X55/a3a3a3/fff"></img>'; break;
} document.getElementById("img01").innerHTML = image;
}

function change02() {
var image = "";
var answers = document.getElementById("txt02").value;
switch(answers) {
case "a": image='<img src="https://dummyimage.com/55X55/00a2ff/fff"></img>'; break;
case "b": image='<img src="https://dummyimage.com/55X55/1eff00/fff"></img>'; break;
case "c": image='<img src="https://dummyimage.com/55X55/ff0000/fff"></img>'; break;
case "":  image='<img src="https://dummyimage.com/55X55/000000/fff"></img>'; break;
default:  image='<img src="https://dummyimage.com/55X55/a3a3a3/fff"></img>'; break;
} document.getElementById("img02").innerHTML = image;
}
```

**CSS**

```
#sideright, #sideleft{
  float:left;
  width:180px;
}

#sideleft div{
  float:left;
  border:1px solid red;
  width:55px;
  height:55px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simply by passing an argument to your function. That's what arguments are for.

Write one parametric function :

```
function change( num ) { // <-- here num=='01' or '02'
    var image = "";
    var answers = document.getElementById("txt" + num ).value; // txt01, txt02
    switch(answers) {
         case "a": image='<img src="https://dummyimage.com/55X55/00a2ff/fff"></img>'; break;
         case "b": image='<img src="https://dummyimage.com/55X55/1eff00/fff"></img>'; break;
         case "c": image='<img src="https://dummyimage.com/55X55/ff0000/fff"></img>'; break;
         case "":  image='<img src="https://dummyimage.com/55X55/000000/fff"></img>'; break;
         default:  image='<img src="https://dummyimage.com/55X55/a3a3a3/fff"></img>';                            break;
    } document.getElementById("img" + num ).innerHTML = image; // img01, img02
}
```

Then call it with a different argument each time :

```
<input class="box" id="txt01" type="text" value="" onblur="change('01')"/>
<input class="box" id="txt02" type="text" value="" onblur="change('02')"/>
```